# Which terminal is that?

Tags: windows, bash, qt, linux-terminal, windows-terminal

While watching [Introduction tutorial to Qt / QML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8NSN.jpg) I noticed Jesper Pedersen from KDAB seems to be using a Windows terminal which is not that old (classic) DOS command prompt I'm used to. Seems to be cool, it even has colors.

May I ask what terminal is that?

[image]

Comment: Looks like Git Bash.

Comment: link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxyTkXLbcV4. He calls it "shell" so it could be putty or another type of shell too. Git bash too

Comment: The path showing as `/C/blackie/KDAB/...` looks very like Git Bash.

Comment: But the red background on the time at the begining of the line perhaps no

Comment: You can use foreground and background colors in the Bash or other Linux shell prompts, whatever the terminal, by inserting codes in the PS1 system variable. Like this `PS1='\[\e[1;07m\]\u@\h \w\$\[\e[0m'`